# Web Chart - External REST API

Tags: chart-web-part

I am to build a dashboard that displays statistics that are retrieved from an external web services.

So essentially I need to be able to call a REST service take the results and input them into something consumable by the web charts web part, such as a list.

Any suggestions on potential ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It matters how much access you have and how often it'd have to run.

If it will have to run on a schedule, I'd suggest building a [timer job](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/guruketepalli/archive/2012/01/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-timer-job-send-an-email.aspx) that uses `WebClient` calls to the REST service and writes it to SharePoint.

If it only has to run once, you could just write a console app in C# on the server using the SharePoint Object Model.

If you don't have access to the server, use the SharePoint Client Object model to write from a remote machine to a sharepoint list.